# phpMyAdmin throws No Index Defined! even though indexes and PK's exist

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, relational-database

UPDATE: I have a ticket into my hosting provider (FatCow) as they are able to duplicate the issue. I will post any conclusions here.

I have a MySQL database like so:

```
table || pk
-----------
performers -> pID
genres -> gID
venues -> vID
```

I also have an events table that looks something like this:

```
eID (PK)
ePerformer (INDEX)
eGenre (INDEX)
eVenue (INDEX)
```

They are all the same type: `INT(11)`. All of the tables are `InnoDB`. I want to setup the relationships in `phpMyAdmin` using the Relation View on the events table, but when I try to save:

```
ePerformer: performers->pID ON DELETE RESTRICT, ON UPDATE RESTRICT
eGenre: genres->gID ON DELETE RESTRICT, ON UPDATE RESTRICT
etc...
```

I get this error back for each field: `No index defined!`

I thought perhaps I was doing it backwards, so I tried setting each relationship from the other tables but I'm getting the same error.

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

Using a similar structure I am able to create the relations. You've already checked several of the obvious things (primary key on the referenced keys, InnoDB, etc).

When I first created the `events` table, using the phpMyAdmin dropdown to select INDEX for each of the three fields you indicate, it created a composite index on all three fields, which didn't work; I had to remove that index and manually create an INDEX on each field individually.

The composite index:
[image: The composite index that doesn't work]

The working individual indexes:

[image: Individual indexes that do work]

You could try the Designer feature (which requires you to set up the "[phpMyAdmin configuration storage](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage)"); I find it superior to the Relation View when manipulating relations.

From the `events` table (I know, you already said you were on the proper table), click the Structure tab and next the Relation View link, you should be able to do this:

[image: Relation view example]

In this case I had already created the `events_ibfk_1` relationship through Designer and `fk_venue` through Relation View; this screenshot was taken just prior to creating the `fk_performer` one so what you see here is exactly what I had in place before clicking "Save".

Not sure if that helps any, but I'm able to do it with what you've provided...so maybe if it still doesn't work you can export your complete existing table structure and I'll try to make that work.

For what it's worth, here's the export of the table structure I had working:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
  `eID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ePerformer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `eGenre` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `eVenue` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `genres` (
  `gID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `g` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `performers` (
  `pID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `venues` (
  `vID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE `events`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`eID`), ADD KEY `i_perf` (`ePerformer`), ADD KEY `i_genre` (`eGenre`), ADD KEY `i_venue` (`eVenue`);

ALTER TABLE `genres`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`gID`);

ALTER TABLE `performers`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`pID`);

ALTER TABLE `venues`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`vID`);


ALTER TABLE `events`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_performer` FOREIGN KEY (`ePerformer`) REFERENCES `performers` (`pID`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `events_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`eGenre`) REFERENCES `genres` (`gID`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_venue` FOREIGN KEY (`eVenue`) REFERENCES `venues` (`vID`);
```

Comment: What a great and detailed answer. It appears you are using a newer version of phpMyAdmin than I am. I may simply try running the SQL commands when I have a chance. I don't know whether this would make a difference, but the database tables were imported from my production machine. I exported/imported using .SQL extension. Could this cause unexpected problems if the MySQL servers were different versions? I'm just trying to figure out out why this might happen.
Also, I was sure not to use composite keys, which was a great thing to point out in your answer.

Comment: I just dropped my entire database thinking perhaps it was corrupt. I rebuilt it from phpMyAdmin using the same commands as you have demonstrated above. When I go into Relation View to set the default action on update and delete, I could see that the foreign keys were set to reference the correct primary keys. When I attempted to add RESTRICT as the update and delete actions, I got the same original error! And when I click back into the Relation View, the constraints are gone.